# How to find voice networktype or phone type in case of wifi calling In android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, voip, voice

I need to find out the voice network type or phone type in case of wifi calling.  I tried with below approaches

1) Get getNetworkType from TelephonyManager class.
2) Get getVoiceNetworkType (Hidden method ) from TelephonyManager class.
3) Get getPhoneType from TelephonyManager class.

But none of methods work to get network type or phone type in case of wifi calling.

I have gone through the code for wifi calling https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/c86ff4c72e0f86bc2591eee7df47278af36ee2c3/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony

Am expecting phone type as IMSphone from getPhoneType but not its working. and voicenetwork type returning invalid values in case of wifi calling.

I have T- mobile Samsung S3 with wifi calling enabled.